# Base Change Theorem in the inverse other

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I suspect this may be an error or an typing error, but I cannot be sure.

In https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/19890/1/ModulGeneralHiggs.pdf (line 2, page 9) it is claimed that $f_{X,*}\pi_Y^* \simeq \pi_T^* f_*$ refering to the following square
\begin{array}{ccc}
Y\times X & \overset{f_X}\to & T\times X
\cr\downarrow \pi_Y&&\downarrow \pi_T
\cr
Y& \overset{f}\to &T
\end{array}.

The given reference is Hartshorne III 9.3 (Base Change Theorem), but the order is wrong. From there I only get $\pi_{Y,*}f_X^* \simeq f^* \pi_{T,*} $.

Is this wrong or is there a way to get the Base Change Theorem in this "inverse" order?

Comment: The $\pi$'s are flat, just flip the diagram.